# ListView Selected Row's column value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, c#-4.0

I have a ListView in my Visual C# code that also implements double click listener on a row. The double click show display one of the column value of that row ( id in this case ).

Here is the xaml code:

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" 
          Height="334" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="10,62,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="630" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"

              >
        <ListView.View >
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="id" Width="35" Header="Id"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=id}" ></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=address}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Mobile" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=mobile}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=date}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=price}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Warranty" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=warranty}"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And the C# code:

```
public view_all()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myList.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(list_MouseDoubleClick);



    }

    private void list_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myList.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            string selectedItem = myList.Items[myList.SelectedIndex].ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(selectedItem);
        }
    }
```

On Click the Message Box displays 'System.Data.DataRowView'. The message should be the id of that row.

Answer (score 0):

So, a ListItem is a single container if memory serves me, so it should have an implicit .Content property where you can put your fingers and reach for what is inside.

Right now, since you didn't do that, it is telling you basically the type of container that your value is inside

try accessing myList.Items[myList.SelectedIndex].Content.ToString()

(or something like it, I'm not near a development environment right now) which will help you target the right thing.

Hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

The subitem here depends on what column your id in the listview is.

```
 string selectedItem = myList.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
```